# Show specific value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where in each row for each id we have 'Client' column. When a user clicks on the row he is able to change client. I am using jquery.dialog for this operation. When a dialog appears the user sees a dropdownlist with Clients. How I can make that after dialog appears, the user sees the current client as the selected item in the dropdown? I've tried as below:

```
onDblClickRow: function (row, $element) {
    $.getJSON('/ManageProjects/GetAvaibleClients/', function (clients) {
        if (clients.length == 0) {
            $('#clientNameEdit').empty();
            $('#clientNameEdit').append('<option value="0">Tasks</option>');
        }
        $.each(clients, function (index, clientt) {
            $('#clientNameEdit').append("<option value='" + clientt.Value + "'>" + clientt.Text + "</option>");
        });
    })
   var currentClient = row.clientName; // Client name from Row
   $('#clientNameEdit select').val(currentClient); // Tried to set like that 
}
```

but doesn't work

Comment: Replace `$('#clientNameEdit select').val` to `$('#clientNameEdit').val`. It's seems that the `#clientNameEdit` is that `select` itself.

Comment: Also doesn't work :(

Comment: + insert the rows that start with `var currentClient = row.clientName;` into the `$.getJSON callback`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following alteration to your code snippet should do the trick:

```
onDblClickRow: function (row, $element) {
            $.getJSON('/ManageProjects/GetAvaibleClients/', function (clients) {
                if (clients.length == 0) {
                    $('#clientNameEdit').empty();
                    $('#clientNameEdit').append('<option value="0">Tasks</option>');
                }
                $.each(clients, function (index, clientt) {
                    $('#clientNameEdit').append("<option value='" + clientt.Value + "'>" + clientt.Text + "</option>");
                });
                var currentClient = row.clientName; // Client name from Row
                $('#clientNameEdit').val(currentClient); // Tried to set like that but doesn't work                
            });
```

As indicated above, if you do the currentClient = row.clientName outside the success of the ajax call, it will probably fire before the dropdown is populated and therefore not have any effect.

Secondly the jQuery selector `'#clientNameEdit select'` should only be `'#clientNameEdit'` as it refer to the dropdown itself and not it's parent.

Comment: $('#clientNameEdit').val(currentClient); after this line dropdown become blank

Comment: just evaluate the value returned by var currentClient = row.clientName. That might be the reason for the dropdown being blank as it returned a value that is not in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

The value passed in to `.val` needs to be the `clientt.Value` and not the text name.

if you dont have the `clientt.Value`, then try something like:-

```
$("#clientNameEdit option[text=" + currentClient + "]").attr("selected", true);
```

And bring the setting of the `select` inside of the `success` function.